# Unable to send Mail using smtp relay, Ruby mail gem

Tags: ruby, email, smtp, relay

I'm trying to send an email using the 'mail' gem (packaging using OCRA), but I'm getting an error message:

```
=== Loading script to check dependencies
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:
13:in `check_from': SMTP From address may not be blank: nil (ArgumentError)
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/check_delive
ry_params.rb:6:in `check'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/network/deli
very_methods/smtp.rb:97:in `deliver!'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:2
149:in `do_delivery'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:2
39:in `deliver'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/mail.rb:141:
in `deliver'
        from c:/BacklogAlert.rb:140:in `send_email'
        from c:/BacklogAlert.rb:163:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `lo
ad'
        from C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/ocra:22:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby23/bin/ocra:22:in `<main>'
```

The problem is that we're using an internal smtp mail relay which only allows devices to send to internal recipients, so the "from" address isn't needed.

Here's my code:

```
  Mail.defaults do
      delivery_method :smtp, mail_options
    end

    Mail.deliver do
           to email_recipient
         from email_sender
      subject 'Test email ' + today_date
         body 'Attached is a file'
         add_file test_file
       end
```

How do i get the email to send without specifying a "from" address?

Comment: Did you try with a dummy FROM address?

Comment: You don't.  The MTA is going to require one anyway.  Actually, the SMTP protocol itself requires one; you have to have one to 'speak' SMTP.  You at least have to specify a blank address to the MAIL FROM: in an SMTP transaction.

Comment: `localhost` is giving me authentication errors.  Did you get this fixed?  My `localhost` workstation doesn't have a `FQDN` so it isn't working and I'm also looking to solve this.